# Casting Dataset internal type from Assoc to Struct

Tags: formatting, dataset, associations

Using:

```
planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}];
```

The full form of this projection displays the internal type def:

```
planets[1 ;; 2, KeyDrop["Moons"]] // FullForm

(* ... Assoc[Atom[String], Struct[{"Mass", "Radius"}, {Atom[1 kg]],Atom[1 km]}], AnyLength] ...*)
```

Formatted:

[image]

Whereas projection by Span, in 2nd slot, will cast the type - known issue as per Taliesin's comments elsewhere - casts `Struct` to an `Assoc` (TypeSystem is undocumented).

```
planets[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2] // FullForm

(* ... Assoc[Atom[String], Assoc[Atom[String], AnyType, 2], AnyLength] ... *)
```

[image]

I need to go the other direction (motivation: need to re-thread `Keys` after Outer product which currently doesn't support `Associations`).

```
data = <|1 -> <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"|>, 2 -> <|1 -> "c", 2 -> "d"|>|> //
    Dataset // FullForm

(* ... Assoc[Atom[Integer], Assoc[Atom[Integer], Atom[String], 2], 2] ... *)
```

Why does this fail, using `Dataset` constructor's 2nd argument. I think I'm using the same template except for the type specifics:

```
Dataset[<|1 -> <|1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"|>, 2 -> <|1 -> "c", 2 -> "d"|>|>, 
 Assoc[Atom[Integer], Struct[{1, 2}, {Atom[String], Atom[String]}], 
  AnyLength]]

(* Dataset::data: "Data does not conform to type Assoc[Atom[Integer],Struct[{1,2},{Atom[String],Atom[String]}],AnyLength]."  *)
```

Comment: It seems it would work if 1 and 2 were strings. Btw, I don't get the types by using FullForm

Comment: @Rojo, what do you see w/ `FullForm` - only the data?

Comment: Sorry, I do see it, my bad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Structs can only have string keys. That's hard to justify theoretically, but it's easy to justify practically :)